# Mostrar en 1 columna valores seperados por coma

Tags: oracle

necesito realizar un select sobre un campo seperado por comas, la idea es mostrar este resultado en una sola columna pero distintas filas, ejemplo:

tengo:

```
SELECT 'CORREO1', 'CORREO2', 'CORREO3' FROM DUAL;
```

resultado:

```
CORREO1 | CORREO2 | CORREO3
----------------------------
CORREO1 | CORREO2 | CORREO3
```

pero lo necesito asi:

```
CORREOS
-------
CORREO1
CORREO2
CORREO3
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No es lo mismo que tengas un campo separado por coma a lo que estas mostrando. Son dos casos totalmente distintos. Podes aclarar bien cual es tu escenario?

Comment: Para evitar que te pongan negativo te pido que corrijas tu redacción indicando que: tienes una consulta que devuelve un solo registro con tres columnas y deseas convertirla en una consulta que devuelva una sola columna con 3 filas.

Answer (score 1):

Debe bastar con aplicar un unpivot

```
SELECT UNIDA
  FROM ( 
           SELECT 'CORREO 1' A
                , 'CORREO 2' B 
                , 'CORREO 3' C 
             FROM DUAL
       )
UNPIVOT (   UNIDA FOR  frase IN ( A, B, C));
```